# How to remove toc title in KOMAscript classes?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

In the "normal" classes one can remove the TOC title (the "Content" heading) with

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@starttoc{toc}}
```

But when I do this on KOMAScript classes (e.g. `scrartcl`) this also changes some other settings (e.g. vertical spaces) of KOMAscript which I don't want to change.

**How can I remove only the table of contents' headline without changing anything else?**

Note: I don't want the line to be empty (so, not an empty string `""`, like `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}` would do), but so that the headline is not there at all and the space gets "freed".

Comment: See my updated solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `\phantom` command provides help here: It acts and uses the box for the `\contentsname` content, as if it would be present, but outputs an empty box with the correct dimensions.

However, the original `\contentsname` content has to be stored via a `\let` 
command to some other macro, before it can be redefined.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}


% Redefine the contentsname, but save it before...
\let\LaTeXStandardContentsName\contentsname
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\phantom{\LaTeXStandardContentsName}}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents%
\clearpage

\section{First}
\clearpage
\section{Second}
```

[image]

The 'same' code without `\renewcommand` provides the `\contentsname` above, without vertical shift.

---

---

After some misunderstandings the solution seems to be the `\deftocheading{toc}{}` approach, a somewhat hidden command in the manual ;-)

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}

\deftocheading{toc}{}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents%
\clearpage

\section{First}
\clearpage
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does still only "hide" the toc title, but does not "free" the vertical space it used.

Comment: @FooBar: There was no line that you want "free" the space ;-)

Comment: There was, in the question the last line starting with "Note: ". ;) But I made it even more clear now. :)

Comment: @foobar: Now it is there, previously there was only `no heading at all`, not `space be freed` ;-)